# Install kernel 5.15.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kernel, glibc

I installed the newer 5.15.0 kernel onto my Linux Mint 19.3 (Ubuntu 18.04) by https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh .

All worked fine, but not for kernel headers which gave me an installation error due to the expected LIBC version that must be >= 2.34, instead of Ubuntu 18.04 that is shipped with the 2.27.

Is is possible to solve this issue without compromise the system stability?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved compiling the new kernel on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily install a new kernel with its kernel headers from mainline.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Use `mainline --list` to list available kernels (see `mainline --help`)

to install the `5.15` kernel version, use:

```
mainline --install 5.15.0
```

the above command will install the kernel and the `linux-headers` pacakge.

The GUI can be launched through:

```
mainline-gtk
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same error on headers and LIBC.